# no javascript code execution in phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova

My problem is that when compile and test my application in some sections of the application seems not to execute javascript code

I noticed that when I try the same sections in the browser when first loaded have the same behavior as the compiled application, but when I reloaded the page executes the code javascritp

behavior can be seen in this link

http://jeanca.com/clientes/bluepages/search/specialist.html

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with how you're wrapping this app up for PhoneGap:

1. You're including a javascript file (prettify.js) from a remote server (which redirects to yet another server). Include this file locally with your build
2. In at least one place in your code, you're creating local links instead of properly qualified URLs e.g.

   $('#especialidades').append('<dd><a href="specialistList.html?id=' + data[0][i]+'">'+data[1][i]+'</a></dd>');

Inside PhoneGap, that href will be interpreted as `href=file://specialistList.html?...`. You should put the fully qualified URL there e.g. `href://yourserver.com/specialistList.html?...`

You should also ensure that that all the external servers you use are whitelisted in the PhoneGap project config.

Comment: and solve the problem.

jquery mobile for having a link in another folder need to add data-ajax = "false" to the <a